# discord.js bot is giving an error when setting presence

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

i'm trying to get my bot to set a presence, but it gives me `Cannot read property 'setActivity' of null`
. here's that part of the code:

```
bot.login(token);

bot.user.setActivity('activity', { type: 'WATCHING'})
```

tell me if you need anything else to resolve it.
thanks!

Comment: Please avoid using tags that aren't related to the question. Java and JavaScript are not "related"

Comment: @innis sorry I won't do that again :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your bot isn't ready yet.

Try to put your function inside a ready event like this :

```
bot.once('ready', () => {
    bot.user.setActivity('activity', { type: 'WATCHING'});
});
```

By the way, make sure to place the `bot.login()` part afterwards (like, on the last line of your file)